# To unlock the stage

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry, limerick

> Sometimes I'm needed when you go out to dine;
>   Sometimes I mean to hurt or malign;
>   But in today's age;
>   To unlock the stage;
>   I grant you the power to steer through the vine.

What am I?

Edit: I meant for a relatively abstract interpretation of "stage" and "vine". Also, the intended answer is not a physical tool or utensil.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes I'm needed when you go out to dine;

> People like to take pictures of their food and post it.

Sometimes I mean to hurt or malign;

> Cyber bullying is very real, and goes a lotfurther than middle school/high schools.

But in today's age;
To unlock the stage;

> The stage being anything you want it to be, but it provides the audience to watch your "performance" on your "stage".

I grant you the power to steer through the vine.

> The 'vine' being the internet, and a reference to a once popular app.

So you are:

> Social Media

Comment: Not the intended answer but I'll give it the check mark on merit. Nice job. The intended answer was rot13(fjvcr, v.r. gb fjvcr lbhe pneq gb cnl sbe qvaare; gb "gnxr n fjvcr ng"; gb haybpx naq fjvcr guebhtu lbhe cubar)

Answer (score 2):

In a literal sense,

> Knife seems to fit

---

> Knives are used for dining
>  Knives can be used to harm
>  Knives can be used to unlock stages in video games (ex. Cut the rope)
>  Knives can help you steer through vines (machete)

Comment: Added an edit in response

Comment: Thanks, I figured that it wasn't meant to be taken literally.